# Wie sagt man "I am concious about" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar

> Ich bin darüber bewusst, worum vorgeht.

```
I am conscious about what is going on.
```

Wie sagt man "I'm conscious about what's going on" auf Deutsch?

Comment: have you consulted a dictionary?? also shouldn't it be *conscious* ? [linguee helps](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=conscious+about)

Comment: Conscious doesn't really make sense there in English I don't think. Aware would work better.

Comment: I marvel at you posts. Both German or English are either clunky or downright wrong. Wherever do you come up with these?

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that everyone so far who has commented has been scathingly critical, yet all have either typos or grammatical errors.  I'd recommend that you all 1) fix your own errors before pointing out those of others, and 2) quit being jerks.  People are here to be helped, not insulted.

Comment: I don't take their insults personal, but some people do a better job in insulting people's grammatical errors, than helping them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German construction is „sich einer Sache bewusst sein“. Hence a grammatically correct version is

> Ich bin mir dessen, das vorgeht, bewusst.

The relative clause can also be moved to the end. However, that is needlessly complicated. An easier variant is

> Mir ist bewusst, was vorgeht.

If you want to know what the construction was if „über“ was the right proposition, there is also the construction „sich über etwas im Klaren sein“. The example here becomes.

> Ich bin mir über das, was vorgeht, im Klaren.

or:

> Ich bin mir darüber im Klaren, was vorgeht.